# Negative Binomial Regression with Non-Negative Coefficients

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, constrained-regression

I am working with counts data and I need the estimated coefficients for the mean to be non-negative for interpretation reasons.

So far, the only two packages support this are addreg and glmnet. However, addreg only suppports Negative Binomial 1 (NB1), but I want NB2 model.

As for the glmnet package, I have two problems about it: First, I keep encountering the error "algorithm did not convergeWarning". There are some threads about why this error would occur in binary data, but I have no clue as to why this would occur when I have count data or how to fix it. In addition, in glmnet, the size parameter is user-supplied rather than estimated. Since I don't have a good idea about what a correct or optimal size parameter is, I'd like it to be estimated.

Anyone has any idea about how I should do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you read this CV thread? [Computing different types of negative binomial regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419304/computing-different-types-of-negative-binomial-regression)

Comment: @dipetkov I read the thread, but the gamlss package the said thread discussed doesn't seem to support non-negative regression?