# Statistical testing: do count data come from the same distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, poisson-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

The data I am dealing with are groups of counts, $n_i, i=1..K$. More than a half of these counts are zeros. The null hypothesis is that all the counts come from the same distribution, e.g., Poisson with parameter $\lambda$
$$P(n|\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda},$$ in which case I can perform the estimate of the parameter as the mean over all the counts,
$$\hat{\lambda}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^Kn_i.
$$

There might be however situations where the zero and non-zero counts are generated by different distributions (possibly more than two). I need a statistical test to identify such cases.

**Clarification:** the problem is not to test whether the distribution is Poissonian, but whether *all* counts come from the distribution or not. Zeros may be due to $\lambda$
being small... or because they are permanently zero. (I realized after the discussion in the comments, that the initial formulation of my questions is ambiguous.)

Comment: You appear to change the question at the very end.  If the zero and non-zero counts are "generated by different distributions," then exactly what is you model for them?  It's obviously not Poisson!

Comment: @whuber if they are generated by different processes, then my null hypothesis is incorrect. For simplicity, one can consider that non-zero counts are still generated from a Poisson distribution, but zeros are just zeros - nothing happens.

Comment: Couldn't you do a test for overdispersion in a Poisson model (as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66586/is-there-a-test-to-determine-whether-glm-overdispersion-is-significant), for example)? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: It sounds like most Poisson tests would apply, but if you could be more specific about your alternate hypothesis one might be able to develop a more powerful test appropriate for it.

Comment: @whuber the problem is not to test whether the distribution is Poissonian, but whether *all* counts come from the distribution or not. Zeros may be due to $\lambda$ being small... or because they are permanently zero.

Comment: @COOLSerdash thank you for pointing this! Indeed, the approach that I have adopted for now is to test the variance of the process vs. its mean.

Comment: In the abstract setting you describe, I cannot determine what you might mean by "all counts come from the distribution" or by "permanently zero."  These phrases might make sense in a particular application, so consider disclosing that in your post.

Comment: @whuber In my experience giving too many technical details in this SE guarantees that the question remains unanswered... One way to describe the situation would be as a zero-inflated distribution - but this suggests specific kind of answers.

Comment: In my experience, almost all questions that are stated abstractly fail to capture the unique or important aspects of the application, risking answers that are useless or misleading.

Comment: @whuber I am ready to modify the question or provide additional information, if someone is interested in answering it. E.g., I have tried to give you multiple clarifications in the comments above... but I am even not sure, whether you are trying to answer or simply going through the motions of a moderator managing the community. Please do jot take it as an offense, but we are all busy people, and so since posting the question I have learned more by googling than from the community

Comment: As you suppose, I am only trying to help you articulate an understandable, answerable question.  I am not offended when that doesn't happen, but I do appreciate knowing when it would not be worth the time to continue.

Answer (score 4):

You can test the null hypothesis that the data follows a Poisson distribution against the alternative of a [zero-inflated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) Poisson using for example the `glmmTMB` R-package.  The test relies on the likelihood ratio test statistic being asymptotically chi-square with one degree of freedom.

However, unless you also allow zero-deflation under your alternative hypothesis, the null hypothesis of no zero-inflation is on the boundary of the parameter space, and the likelihood ratio statistic is then asymptotically distributed as an equal-weights mixture of chi-squares with zero and one degree of freedom [(Stram and Lee 1994)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2533455) so a better approximate $p$-value would be half of what is computed below.

```r
# Simulated data from a zero-inflated poisson
set.seed(1)
y <- rpois(100, lambda = 3)
y[1:10] <- 0
data <- data.frame(y)

# Testing Poisson against zero-inflated Poisson relying on asymptotic distribution of likelihood ratio statistic
library(glmmTMB)
mod0 <- glmmTMB(y ~ 1, family=poisson, data)
mod1 <- update(mod0, ziformula = ~ 1)
anova(mod0, mod1)
#> Data: data
#> Models:
#> mod0: y ~ 1, zi=~0, disp=~1
#> mod1: y ~ 1, zi=~1, disp=~1
#>      Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
#> mod0  1 383.93 386.53 -190.96   381.93                           
#> mod1  2 380.88 386.09 -188.44   376.88 5.0513      1    0.02461 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```